# Swagger doc showing 'semantic error' in editor

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

After generating the swagger-yaml file for swagger doc creation and using editor.swagger.io, I am getting semantic errors as below. I don't have any clue so far for this tag error below:

```
    Semantic error at paths./v1/entitlement/{entitlementId}.put.parameters.5.schema.$ref
    $ref values must be RFC3986-compliant percent-encoded URIs
    Jump to line 391
    Semantic error at paths./v1/entitlements/{skuId}.post.parameters.4.schema.$ref
    $ref values must be RFC3986-compliant percent-encoded URIs
    Jump to line 700
    Semantic error at paths./v1/entitlements/{skuId}.post.responses.200.schema.$ref
    $ref values must be RFC3986-compliant percent-encoded URIs
    Jump to line 710
```

The code:

SwaggerConfig.java - To configure the swagger2 properties for the corresponding application controller.

```
package com.pearson.gsam.product.management.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

import static springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Profile({ "dev", "qa","local","stg","it" })
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Value("${application.name}")
    String appName;
    @Value("${application.description}")
    String appDescription;
    @Value("${application.version}")
    private String appVersion;

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiEndPointsInfo());
    }


    private ApiInfo apiEndPointsInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title(appName)
                .description(appDescription)
                .version(appVersion)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");

    }
}
```

SwaggerDoc.java - To the creation of swagger-API.YAML file and stored on the particular directory

```
    package docs;
    
    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.Writer;
    
    import com.pearson.gsam.product.management.entitlement.service.ProductManagementEntitlementService;
    import com.pearson.gsam.product.management.entitlement.service.ProductManagementEntitlementServiceImpl;
    import com.pearson.gsam.product.management.kafka.EventService;
    import com.pearson.gsam.product.management.kafka.KafkaCallBackHandler;
    import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBeans;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
    import org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafka;
    import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
    import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
    
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLMapper;
    import com.pearson.gsam.product.management.config.SwaggerConfig;
    import com.pearson.gsam.product.management.entitlement.ProductManagementEntitlementApplication ;
    
    @ActiveProfiles( "it" )
    @DirtiesContext
    @SpringBootTest(classes = {SwaggerConfig.class},
            properties = {"spring.profiles.active=it"})
    //@SpringBootTest(classes = ProductManagementEntitlementApplication.class)
    @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoAutoConfiguration.class, KafkaAutoConfiguration.class})
    @AutoConfigureMockMvc
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.pearson.gsam.product.management.controller", "springfox"})
    //@EmbeddedKafka
    @MockBeans(
            @MockBean( classes = { ProductManagementEntitlementService.class, EventService.class
                    })
    )
    @Import(SwaggerConfig.class)
    public class SwaggerDoc {
        @Value("${service-name}")
        String serviceName;
        
        @Autowired
        private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
        @Test
        public void generateSwagggerDoc() throws Exception {
            String contentAsString = mockMvc.perform(get("/v2/api-docs"))
                    .andDo(print())
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andReturn()
                    .getResponse().getContentAsString();
    
            // parse JSON
            JsonNode jsonNodeTree = new ObjectMapper().readTree(contentAsString);
            // save it as YAML
            String jsonAsYaml = new YAMLMapper().writeValueAsString(jsonNodeTree);
    
            File file = new File("swagger/"+serviceName+"-API_Swagger.yml");
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    
            try (Writer writer = new FileWriter(file)) {
                IOUtils.write(jsonAsYaml, writer);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using the below jars for swagger:

```
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
        compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.10.0'
```

Comment: next time please format your question properly. that was a really lousy attempt

Comment: sure@JamesZ, some network issue was there while posting and duplicacy had occurred

Comment: I would suggest sharing the OpenAPI/Swagger specification that you're using in the Swagger Editor (or is generated by the application). It's hard identifying it by taking a look at the error from Swagger validator and referring to incomplete code. Or you can share the code for controllers and remove the actual working of the controller to keep it clean.

Answer (score 0):

The follow fixed me mistake:
In the @Controller class I had the path: `/v1/example/{idRequest}`
And like method's parameter I had:

> `(@PathVariable("idRequest") @ApiParam(name = "idRequest", value = "id de la solicitud sobre la que se realizará el cambio", example = "EXAMPLE", required = true) String idRequest)`

The same mistake was solved to delete @ApiParam and the value of @PathVariable and stay me only:
`(@PathVariable() String idRequest)`